# Echoing variables from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some PHP code that sets variables from a database. I'll explain, please let me know if it does not make sense.

So, I have a query to select `*` from the table if `class = '$class'`. That all works I got it working.

I then set the variables like this `$id = $row["id"];` and that all works, in my HTML code I have `<p><?php echo $id?></p>` and if their `class = $class` it will display it, however, if it does not meet those requirements the variables are not set, so I get the error `Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\wamp64\www\studentplanner\account\homework.php on line 73`.

What I want to do is only output the results in HTML if the requirement was met.

No idea if that makes sense or not!

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM homework WHERE class = '$class'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $id = $row["id"];
      $teacher_set = $row["teacher_set"];
      $class = $row["class"];
      $name = $row["name"];
      $description = $row["description"];

    }
}


          <p><?php echo $id?></p>
          <p><?php echo $teacher_set?></p>
          <p><?php echo $class?></p>
          <p><?php echo $name?></p>
          <p><?php echo $description?></p>
```

Comment: You need to show us the actual code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: no @MagnusEriksson it is not.

Comment: It is defined but I want to make it so the HTML code only outputs if results are given in the db

Comment: If your query doesn't produce any results, the $id (and the rest of the variables) won't be set but your code will still try to echo them. So, in some cases, you will try and use some variables that are undefined, which is what the dupe is talking about.

Comment: I get that and I want to make it so it won't echo them unless they are set...

Comment: Check if they are defined first. `if (isset($id)) { ...your html... }`. (Which the answer in the dupe _also_ mentions so, still a dupe).

Comment: Do you expect that query returns one row?

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($result);` to show us your output of the execution?
That would make your question more complete, and easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set flag variable before while loop then use that variable to decide whether to print data in html or not

```
$data_exist = false;
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $data_exist = true; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $id = $row["id"];
      $teacher_set = $row["teacher_set"];
      $class = $row["class"];
      $name = $row["name"];
      $description = $row["description"];

    }
}


if($data_exist)
{
?>

          <p><?php echo $id?></p>
          <p><?php echo $teacher_set?></p>
          <p><?php echo $class?></p>
          <p><?php echo $name?></p>
          <p><?php echo $description?></p>
<?php
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM homework WHERE class = '$class'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 ?>  
    <p><?php echo $row["id"];?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row["teacher_set"];?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row["class"];?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row["name"];?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row["description"];?></p>
<?php } } ?>
```